# How to make event requests from specific email addresses go to a specific Google Calendar?

Tags: email, google-calendar, appointments

I have 2 calendars set up in google calendar; Personal & Work.

I want to be able to send/forward meeting request from my work email to my google calendar, but my default calendar is my 'Personal' calendar and that is where the event requests end up, forcing me to have to copy the event request to my 'Work' calendar.

How do I make these requests (coming from my work email address) automatically go to my 'Work' calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can share calendars in google...  It might not be the best answer, but maybe you can create a new calendar/gmail account specifically for the work calendar items and then share that with yourself?

Comment: hmm that seems like a decent workaround if you can't actually do what I am asking, good thinking.